# removing duplicate rows if one of the columns are the same Sql-server

Tags: php, sql-server

i have a query which links table one two table two and gets the last comment for the result in table one, which works but when there are multiple records from table one with the same ID for example it shows that result again here is an example

Query results

```
ID | Machine | description | createdtime |  product code |  work order | qty  | comment | Reson
        No
129  |1 |  A name | 2015-01-08 07:38:41.427 | A code  |   12/14/0038 |  4000  | comment   | Reason
143  |1 |  A name | 2015-01-08 13:30:39.403 | A code  |   12/14/0038 |  4000  | comment    | Reson
130  |4 |  A name | 2015-01-08 07:38:46.540 | A code  |   12/14/0045 |  12000 | comment   | Reason
131  |5 |  A name | 2015-01-08 07:38:50.243 | A code  |   01/15/0001 |  4000  | comment   | Reason
```

As you can see here there are two records with the machine number 1, one created in the morning and one in the after noon, however i only want the latest one to show up, Here is my query.

```
SELECT     Qualitycontrol.ID, Qualitycontrol.MachineNo, Qualitycontrol.Description,        Qualitycontrol.CreatedTime, Qualitycontrol.ProductCode, Qualitycontrol.WorkOrder, 
              Qualitycontrol.Quantity, Qc.Comment, Qc.Reason
FROM         Qualitycontrol 
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM QualityControl_Comments
WHERE Qualitycontrol.ID = QCUID
ORDER BY Qualitycontrol.ID DESC -- whatevet defines order in QualityControl_Comments
) AS Qc                  
WHERE     (Qualitycontrol.CreatedTime BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1,     CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
ORDER BY Qualitycontrol.MachineNo
```

Comment: Try fully qualifying QCUID -- that is, use **QualityControl_Comments.QCUID** in your outer apply scope.  Otherwise I don't see anything wrong with this

Comment: The problem is that it's pulling all the records for the day, however i just want the latest for the day, the part in regards to the comments table is fine

Comment: Ah, my bad.  This might help you: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17217/returning-a-result-set-with-multiple-rows-based-on-max-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work.

```
SELECT     Qualitycontrol.ID, Qualitycontrol.MachineNo, Qualitycontrol.Description,        Qualitycontrol.CreatedTime, Qualitycontrol.ProductCode, Qualitycontrol.WorkOrder, 
              Qualitycontrol.Quantity, Qc.Comment, Qc.Reason
FROM         Qualitycontrol 
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM QualityControl_Comments
WHERE Qualitycontrol.ID = QualityControl_Comments.QCUID
ORDER BY Qualitycontrol.ID DESC -- whatevet defines order in QualityControl_Comments
) AS Qc                  
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Qualitycontrol.MachineNo, MAX(Qualitycontrol.ID) MID
    FROM Qualitycontrol
    GROUP BY Qualitycontrol.MachineNo
) UNQ ON UNQ.MID = Qualitycontrol.ID
WHERE     (Qualitycontrol.CreatedTime BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1,     CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
ORDER BY Qualitycontrol.MachineNo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use somthing like this.
Using row_number you can partition your data by machnine id and sort the numer by date. Than you can just use a simple where clouse to select what you want

```
;WITH CTE
as
(
SELECT     Qualitycontrol.ID, Qualitycontrol.MachineNo, Qualitycontrol.Description,        Qualitycontrol.CreatedTime, Qualitycontrol.ProductCode, Qualitycontrol.WorkOrder, 
              Qualitycontrol.Quantity, Qc.Comment, Qc.Reason
FROM         Qualitycontrol 
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM QualityControl_Comments
WHERE Qualitycontrol.ID = QCUID

) AS Qc                  
WHERE     (Qualitycontrol.CreatedTime BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1,     CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))

), CTE2 as 
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by MachineNo order by CreatedTime desc) as 'row_index' from cte
)
select * from cte2
where row_index = 1
order by MachineNo
```

Comment: Hey, i get these errors Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The multi-part identifier "Qualitycontrol.MachineNo" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The multi-part identifier "Qualitycontrol.CreatedTime" could not be bound.

Comment: Please try now, i can't test the query, but please try now. I have updated the answer

Comment: Yeah this works when i run the query in Microsoft sql server management studio however when i use it in php it's not returning anything do you know why that would be

Comment: Dont't know, i have no expirience with php, but instead you can use the View - just create the view (or procedurę etc) with this query. You should always use the view in the application and shouldn't just use the table in the application code.